# Cannot change text and background color of searchbar in navigation bar

Tags: ios, text, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I've added a searchbar to my navigation bar and want to change the color of the text and background. I'm using the code below and based on other answers on SO `appearanceWhenContainedIn` should work but does nothing. What's going wrong here?

```
UISearchBar * theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)]; // frame has no effect.

    theSearchBar.delegate = self;
    if ( !searchBarPlaceHolder ) {
        searchBarPlaceHolder = @"What are you looking for?";
    }
    theSearchBar.placeholder = searchBarPlaceHolder;
    theSearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;

    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UISearchDisplayController *searchCon = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
             initWithSearchBar:theSearchBar
             contentsController:self ];

    [searchCon setActive:NO animated:YES];
    self.searchDisplayController = searchCon;
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar=YES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code helped me fix the issue. I have read methods that set private API may be rejected from apple, and route to go is subView. See below:

```
    if(!itemSearchBar)
    {
        itemSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
        [itemSearchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 55)];
        itemSearchBar.placeholder = @"What are you looking for?";
        itemSearchBar.delegate = self;


        UITextField* sbTextField;

        for (UIView *subView in self.itemSearchBar.subviews){
            for (UIView *ndLeveSubView in subView.subviews){

                if ([ndLeveSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                {

                    sbTextField = (UITextField *)ndLeveSubView;
                    //changes typing text color
                    sbTextField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
                    //changes background color
                    sbTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                    //changes placeholder color
                            UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
                            sbTextField.attributedPlaceholder =
                            [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                             initWithString:@"What are you looking for?"
                             attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color}];

                    break;
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following piece of code :

```
if(!searchBar)
{
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    //        searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    //        searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 55)];
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search here";
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    UITextField *txfSearchField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    txfSearchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    //[txfSearchField setLeftView:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
    [txfSearchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    txfSearchField.layer.borderWidth = 0.9f;
    txfSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    txfSearchField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor;
    //txfSearchField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navgation_bar.png"];
    //[searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navgation_bar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navgation_bar.png"]];
    //searchBar.barStyle = UISearchBarStyleProminent;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, i'm able to change background color but no luck with the text color. i've tried tintColor and setTintColor. any suggestions?